# Issues with Wireguard routing from a single NIC

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables, wireguard

I am having issues with Wireguard seemingly not routing everything.  Basically I have a ubuntu box at home, where I have installed Wireguard.

I want to be able to connect to that box and access both the LAN and the internet as if I were in my house.

It kinda works. I can tracert and ping without issue. I can access some website with no issues. But if I try something like speedtest.net, I try to download something, or do something like try and use a streaming service. It doesn't work.

I have been playing with this for days, and I am at a loss.

Worth noting I have at the moment a GLiNet box on the same network, I am able to Wireguard into that and there are not issues accessing anything.

They are on the same subnet etc, and are on different inbound ports. So it doesn't look like it is anything to do with my routers or ISP.

wg0.conf (with keys removed)

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.253.1.0/24
ListenPort = 11820
PrivateKey = A private key
MTU = 1450

[Peer]
PublicKey = A public key
PresharedKey = A preshared key
AllowedIPs = 10.253.1.1/32
```

Client conf:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.253.1.1/32
PrivateKey = Public key
DNS = 192.168.101.115,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
MTU = 1450
FwMark = 0xca6c

[Peer]
PublicKey = Public key
PresharedKey = Preshared key
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = <a domain>:11820
PersistentKeepalive = 15
```

/etc/sysctl.conf set as:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

I am currently doing route manually after the connection because I have tried so many solutions.

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.253.1.0/24 -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i enp4s0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i wg0 -o enp4s0 -j ACCEPT
```

This is the best working version I have, where most websites will download all content.

When trying to load speedtest.net, I get the basic HTML, but no CSS etc. Errors:

```
b.cdnst.net/fonts/HCo_fonts.css:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
b.cdnst.net/styles/m…da11a5ad32a75.css:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
amazon.js:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
ad.js:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
groupblack-white_on_black-2x.png:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
b.cdnst.net/javascri…bid.6.18.0.min.js:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
b.cdnst.net/javascri…41d7f51600e38d977:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
www.googletagservice…com/tag/js/gpt.js:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
www.googletagmanager….js?id=GTM-K7SNBZ:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
favicon.ico:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
api.btloader.com/country:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
tag?o=5075500865683456&upapi=true:1 
 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at tag?o=50755008656834…&upapi=true:1:16474
    at tag?o=5075500865683456&upapi=true:1:1259
    at Object.next (tag?o=5075500865683456&upapi=true:1:1364)
    at o (tag?o=5075500865683456&upapi=true:1:107)
api.btloader.com/pv?…2Add7F&upapi=true:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
b.cdnst.net/manifest.webmanifest:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
b.cdnst.net/images/f…icons/favicon.svg:1 
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

For http://icmpcheck.popcount.org/:

> GET http://icmpcheck.popcount.org/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 (OK)

A search from google:

> This site can’t be reached. [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) took too long to respond.
> Try:
>
> Checking the connection
> Checking the proxy and the firewall
> Running Windows Network Diagnostics
>
> ERR_TIMED_OUT

Disney.com loads, looks fine, but has a couple of errors (cleaned up a little):

```
en-US?logLevel=INFO:13          GET https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=6Lck8IUfAAAAABpd98whDTBeR8-QFbpFUYbFcz6P&hl=en net::ERR_TIMED_OUT

(anonymous) @ en-US?logLevel=INFO:13
window.setInitialData @ en-US?logLevel=INFO:13
(anonymous) @ en-US?logLevel=INFO:24
head-56277e6a3815.js:1          GET https://tredir.go.com/capmon/GetDE/?set=j&param=geo&raw=true net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
GET https://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
GET https://dcf.espn.com/TWDC-DTCI/prod/Bootstrap.js net::ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

So short version:
Tunnel into server (192.168.101.119 - Tunnel 10.253.1.0/24) route all traffic from tunnel to LAN (192.168.101.0/24) and the Internet. Ping, tracert all working fine, and some website are fine. Can't use streaming services, can't download files etc, can't use sites like speedtest.com.

I am completely out of ideas, especially as it mostly works.

Any suggestions please.

----------------- updated --------------------

Routing details as follows:

ip r

```
default via 192.168.101.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.101.119 metric 100
8.8.4.4 via 192.168.101.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.101.119 metric 100
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.101.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.101.119 metric 100
10.253.1.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.253.1.0
192.168.101.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.101.119 metric 100
192.168.101.1 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.101.119 metric 100
192.168.101.115 dev enp4s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.101.119 metric 100
```

sudo route -n

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.101.1   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp4s0
8.8.4.4         192.168.101.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp4s0
8.8.8.8         192.168.101.1   255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 enp4s0
10.253.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wg0
192.168.101.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.101.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp4s0
192.168.101.115 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp4s0
```

sudo ufw status

```
Status: inactive
```

The details of the IPs

```
192.168.101.1 - main router (to internet)
8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (google DNS)
192.168.101.115 - Local DNS server
10.253.1.0 used inside the VPN
```

Hopefully this has the additional information to help fault find.  Just for clarity this is the routing table with the VPN connect and all of the post rules applied (which I expect you could already see).

Comment: What _actual symptoms_ of "not working" are you seeing? Does the browser say the domain name wasn't found at all? Does the browser say the connection to the webserver couldn't be made? Does the website suddenly close connection halfway through? Does the connection appear to hang, loading the page forever?

Comment: What other firewall rules do you have, in both tables? Does your setup pass the http://icmpcheck.popcount.org/ test? Does `tracepath` to various sites report the correct MTU?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will check on all those things a little later today.

Comment: I have added details above of what happens for a few sites, inc http://icmpcheck.popcount.org/.
The firewall is turned off on the unix box (to avoid any related issues).  Exactly the same firewall rule apply to the GLiNet as the unix box, so not likely an issue. I am using a windows client to test with, so no tracepath, but using ping -f -l 1422 works fine, with a MTU of 1450, so it would appear not to be MTU.

Comment: As I am sure you have guessed, networking is not my strongest area. If you need me to run some commands on the endpoint ubuntu box, to get more details of the default routing in place, please let me know what you want me to type.

Comment: As you can see some webpages are OK. other completely broken.

Comment: I have added the routing details to the bottom of the of the question. Thank you.